# Concatenation in XSLT and XML generation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that have several variable names such as pathFile, nameFile, fullPath.

Here is my input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <EXTERNALFILES />
  <OCRTEXTFILES />
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val1">val1</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val2">val2</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <INSTANCEVALUE Name="InstanceID">instancevalue</KOFAXVALUE>
  <PATHFILE Sequence="17">C:\myfolder\</TEXTCONSTANT>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I receive from an XML values as PATHFILE (with value "C:\myfolder\") and INSTANCEVALUE (with value "instancevalue")
My objective is to concatenate pathFile and nameFile and to return a full path in the XML generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" 
     indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<ImportDocument DocType="I" 
     xmlns="http://KOFAX_ERT/KOFAX_SAP_DocumentSchema.xsd">
<xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENT">
<xsl:for-each select="./DOCUMENTINDEX">
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="{@Name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</DOCUMENTINDEX>
</xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="pathFile" select="substring-before(./PATHFILE[@Sequence='17'],'.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nameFile" select="substring-before(./INSTANCEVALUE[@Name='InstanceID'],'.')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fullPath" select="concat($pathFile,$nameFile)"/>

    <Attachments>
        <Attachment>
            <FullPath>
               <xsl:value-of select="concat($fullPath,'_signed.pdf')"/>
            </FullPath>
        </Attachment>
    </Attachments>
</xsl:for-each>
</ImportDocument>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect to have this result :

```
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val1">val1</DOCUMENTINDEX>
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val2">val2</DOCUMENTINDEX>
<Attachments>
    <Attachment>
        <FullPath>C:\myfolder\instancevalue_signed.pdf</FullPath>
    </Attachment>
</Attachments>
```

Unfortunatelly it's not returning the expected ouput. 
Result I obtain is the following :

```
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val1">val1</DOCUMENTINDEX>
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="val2">val2</DOCUMENTINDEX>
<Attachments>
  <Attachment>
     <FullPath>_signed.pdf</FullPath>
  </Attachment>
</Attachments>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and the wrong output to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you expect anyone to be able to reproduce your problem with an incomplete snippet where we cannot even tell the context node of the three XPath expressions shown? So please post a minimal but complete stylesheet demonstrating the problem together with the exact output you get for the input sample you have posted.

Comment: I just updated it...

Comment: `select="./DOCUMENTINDEX"` makes no sense for the input sample not containing any element of that name.

Comment: `substring-before(./PATHFILE[@Sequence='17'],'.')` doesn't seem to make sense as there is no `.` in the `PATHFILE` element content.

Comment: I retrieve the ./DOCUMENTINDEX ... I just didn't put the values in the xml ... I'm updating it

Comment: See the first comment and take your time to present *minimal* but *complete* samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. Showing `<ImportDocument DocType="I" xmlns="http://KOFAX_ERT/KOFAX_SAP_DocumentSchema.xsd">` in the XSLT but claiming you get other elements and no namespace at all in the result is not going to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. I was using a collaborator code.

1. I removed the substring-before,
2. I used directly the select value and finally concat
3. I put the xsl:variable tags in Attachment

```
<Attachments>
    <Attachment>
        <xsl:variable name="pathFile" select="PATHFILE[@Sequence='17']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="extension" select="PATHFILE[@Sequence='19']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nameFile" select="INSTANCEVALUE[@Name='InstanceID']"/>
        <FullPath>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat($pathFile, $nameFile, $extension)"/>
        </FullPath>
    </Attachment>
</Attachments>
```